# Batch, Variable vanishes after being set

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I've built a set of code that I'm hoping will achieve the following goals:

1. Pull from a text file the list of files to process via a for loop (easy enough)
2. Take the file name from the token and set it to a variable
3. For that file take each line of text and set it to its own variable.
4. Take the variables and echo them out to a text file in a single line with comma separation

My input (%tlst%) file is simple and contains a list of 5 file names each record residing on its own line:

```
tran.txt1
tran.txt2
tran.txt3
tran.txt4
tran.txt5
```

Each of these files contains 10 lines on which is a single record of information, similar to the following:

```
12345678910111476
2014123456789813186313338
20141030
20141030
840
3597
840
3597
www.test.com
6068
```

What I would expect my results to look like is 5 lines echoed out to a new file (test.txt) that look like the following line:

```
12345678910111476, 2014123456789813186313338, 20141030, 20141030, 840, 3597, 840, 3597, www.test.com, 6068
```

Here is the Code I've got at the moment:

```
@echo=on
Call :Start > c:\temp\test.log 2>&1
:Start
set tlst=C:\temp\test\tlist.txt
For /F "tokens=*" %%H in (%tlst%) Do (
    set Z=%%H
    set Counter=1
    echo %Z%
    echo %Counter%
    For /F "tokens=*" %%x in (%Z%) Do (
        set "Line_!Counter!=%%x"
        echo "Line_!Counter! is %%x 
        set /a Counter+=1
    )
    set /a NumLines=Counter - 1
    Echo %Line_1%, %Line_2%, %Line_3%, %Line_4%, %Line_5%,  %Line_6%, %Line_7%, %Line_8%, %Line_9%, %Line_10%, >> C:\temp\test.txt
    :: or, for arbitrary file lengths:
    for /l %%x in (1,1,%NumLines%) do echo %%x is !Line_%%x!
)
```

What I'm currently running into is the variable I'm setting from my Token in Line 6 doesn't seem to stick... the variable looks like it set, but in the following line 8 when I try to echo the variable it is empty and my next For loop shows the %Z% variable as (NULL). I've also tried to echo the %%H token into a temp file then set the variable by

```
set /p Z=<tempfile
```

but both methods seem to have the same result.

I've also tried adding SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion within my call, but again I don't see any change. I'm kind of lost at this point, so any help would be appreciated. Here is a snippet of what I'm getting in the log file I'm pulling, each entry returns the same error with just a different record in the 2nd line:

```
(
set Z=tran.txt1  
 set Counter=1  
 echo   
 echo   
 For /F "tokens=*" %x in ((null)) Do (
set "Line_!Counter!=%x"  
 echo "Line_!Counter! is %x   
 set /a Counter+=1 
)  
 set /a NumLines=Counter - 1  
 Echo , , , , ,  , , , , ,  1>>C:\temp\test.txt  
 for /L %x in (1 1) do echo %x is !Line_%x! 
)
```

Sorry in advance if I missed any detail I tried to be as clear and complete as I can regarding the detail of what I'm trying to achieve and the process that is taking place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sort of recognize you need delayed expansion, but you are not using it properly.

Normal variable expansion `%Counter%` takes place when the statement is parsed, and the entire parenthesized DO() block is parsed in one pass. So the value is constant within the loop. You need to enable delayed expansion and use `!Counter!` instead. The same is true for `!Z!`, `!Line_1!`, `!Line_2!`, etc.

I don't see why you bother with `!Z!` when you can use `%%H` instead.

You don't need a bunch of Line_n variables - you can simply append each value to the end of the previous value.

You should put an EXIT /B after your CALL so that you do not fall into the subroutine a 2nd time. But you can simply put parentheses around the entire loop and redirect there instead.

The following should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "tlst=c:\temp\test\tlist.txt"

>"c:\temp\test.log" 2>&1 (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%F in ("%tlst%") do (
    set "ln=,"
    for /f "usebackq delims=*" %%L in ("%%~F") do (
      set "ln=!ln!,%%L"
    )
    echo(!ln:~2!
  )
)
```

I used the USEBACKQ option just in case you ever get file paths with spaces in them.

I initialize the `ln` variable with an unwanted character and then strip it out later so that the variable is defined even if there are no values in the file.

Note that FOR variable expansion will be corrupted if delayed expansion is enabled and the value contains `!`. If you ever might run into `!`, then delayed expansion must be toggled on and off within the loop like so:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "tlst=c:\temp\test\tlist.txt"

>"c:\temp\test.log" 2>&1 (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%F in ("%tlst%") do (
    set "ln=,"
    for /f "usebackq delims=*" %%L in ("%%~F") do (
      setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
      for "delims=" %%A in ("!ln!") do (
        endlocal
        set "ln=%%A,%%L"
      )
    )
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!ln:~2!
    endlocal
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response and information. I love to learn how to resolve these issues in the future rather than just being fed a solution with no description. Thank you again!